# Header Cart Resize

Tags: cart, header, mini-cart

I am wanting to resize the cart notifier that you can see at the top right corner of this site: http://testnation.eu/magento/

I have looked through the styles.css but i can't seem to locate where I need to adjust the sizing... can anyone help?

Many thanks.

Comment: Did my answer help? If so, I'd appreciate if you'd consider marking it as the accepted answer by clicking the checkmark next to it...

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your site with the Chrome DevTools enabled, it appears like the site is using SCSS, so make sure that you have a Sass compiler set up. The partial files that are currently styling that element are `_checkout-cart-minicart.scss` and `_header.scss`.

Please let me know in the comments if you have any questions, if this was helpful, and if there are any other ways I can help.